# Issue in Button Click bind on Dom Ready

Tags: php, jquery

I am preparing Html table on Dom ready and trying to click the button in particular row. Below is my code.

```
$.ajax({
    url:            Url + token,
    method:         "POST",
    async:          true,
    data:           JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType:    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (Result) {
        var editButton = '<input type="button" class="EditRole" value="Edit">';
        $.each(Roles, function( key, Role ) {
            var Action = PrepareTd(editButton);
            var tr = '<tr attr-id="' + Role.RoleID + '">' + Action + "</tr>";
            tbody.append(tr);           
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        ErrorCallback(jqXHR);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.EditRole').on("click", function() {
        debugger;
        console.log($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

This never hit debugger. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a event delegation issue Use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", '.EditRole', function() {
        console.log($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add comma after second param and your post will be accepted.